# In a shell script that stores a list of files under a directory, the result values of zsh and bash are different

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

The shell script output values of zsh and bash are different.

This is a shell script that stores a list of files under a specific directory in an array.

```
#!/bin/bash
target_dir="/path/"

list=($( ls ${target_dir} ))
echo ${#list}
```

output : 16

```
#!/bin/zsh
target_dir="/path/"

list=($( ls ${target_dir} ))
echo ${#list}
```

output: 4569

Performed by macos monterey.

bash version : GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0)

zsh version : zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0)

Comment: I would not use the output of `ls` for anything.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the result of ls ?

Comment: *Humans* can use the output of `ls` for its intended informative purposes, but it is not suited to be parsed for interpretation by the shell.  In your particular case, the result is not what you presumably expect if any of the filenames contain spaces, tabs, or newlines.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 3):

> The shell script output values of zsh and bash are different.

Yes, `bash` and `zsh` have differing behavior in some areas, mainly among those not standardized by POSIX, such as arrays.

**In `bash`**, if you expand an array-valued parameter without specifying an index then you get the element at index 0, as if you had said `${an_array[0]}`.  Correspondingly, `${#an_array}` gives you the length of element 0.  If you want to expand the array to all its elements then that is `${an_array[*]}` or `${an_array[@]}`, and if you want the number of elements then that's `${#an_array[*]}` or `${#an_array[@]}`.

**In zsh**, by default, if you expand an array-valued parameter without specifying an index then it is equivalent to expanding `${an_array[*]}`, and, correspondingly, `${#an_array}` gives you the length of that expansion.

You can set the `KSH_ARRAYS` option in zsh to make its behavior in these regards like that of `ksh`, which is the same as that of `bash`, but it would be better for this purpose to simply avoid the plain `${an_array}` and related forms, and in particular, to use `${#an_array[@]}` when you want to determine the number of elements in an array.  This should work the same in zsh and bash.

---

As a separate matter, and as mentioned in comments, do not attempt to parse the output of `ls` programmatically.  It is intended for human consumption only, and it has ambiguities that make it very difficult to parse correctly in all situations.  Plus, globbing is both simpler to write and free of those ambiguities.  Specifically:

```sh
list=("${target_dir}"/*)
```

When either shell expands a shell pattern such as that (after and separate from expanding the parameter reference), each matched filename expands to exactly one word, regardless of the characters it contains.